# Перехват функций под windows

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Доброго вечера! Делал перехват вам по статье http://rsdn.org/article/baseserv/IntercetionAPI.xml 1-м методом. И... Все получилось. Вот только я никак не могу понять принцип, цитирую:

> Практика показала, что вместо обычного jmp лучше применять комбинацию
>   push xxxx ret, где xxxx - адрес заменяющей функции

Так вот, как команда push может заменить jmp? Я бы ещё понял call... Но push, она ведь просто ложит значение в стек (в данном случае - адрес функции), но каким образом она запускает эту функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове `call` выполняется две операции: на стек кладется адрес возврата и происходит переход на процедуру. Т.е. по сути `push` и `jmp`.

При возврате (`ret`) выполняются обратные операции: со стека снимается адрес возврата, и выполняется переход по нему. Т.е. `pop` и `jmp`.

Если сделать `push`, потом `ret`, то это будет эквивалентно `push`, потом `pop`, потом `jmp`. Т.е. с точки зрения стека `push` и `pop` скомпенсируют друг друга (положили на стек, потом снова сняли), и останется просто переход.

Преимущество `push` и `ret` от просто `jmp` может быть в том, что для `jmp` нужно указывать относительный адрес перехода (его еще нужно вычислить), а `ret` со стека берет абсолютный адрес, и переходит по нему.

Можно конечно делать косвенный переход по адресу в регистре (например, `jmp [eax]`), но это может не подойти, если регистры нельзя менять.

В общем, нюансов много, в разных случаях могут быть удобны разные варианты переходов.

Comment: Спасибо, четко и грамотно

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь что делает `ret`? возвращает управление по адресу, сохраненному в стеке. А `push` этот адрес и сохраняет.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Опа, интересно. То есть всю работу ret оказывается совершает, не думал, что она со стеком завязана.   А если просто идёт call какое-то действие ret, то как в стек попадает значение адреса возврата, через call?

Comment: Ну да, call это по сути запихивание адреса возврата в стек и переход.

Comment: Спасибо, принял